# Facebook application now getting "404 Not Found"

Tags: facebook

I have a simple facebook application that serves content off of my primary web server.  I've integrated tabs into my facebook page that accesses this application.  It all worked perfectly. Now, suddenly, I get a "404 Not Found" error on my primary facebook page.

The application itself works fine:

http://apps.facebook.com/composerseries/

But when accessed from within my facebook page as a tab, it now gives the error:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/SONiVOX-Sound-that-Rocks/111857542229788?sk=app_211581618871525

I'm stumped.  I've changed nothing, so it must mean they've recently changed something.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Is it an Iframe Canvas tab?  Everything else has been deprecated for page tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the old FBML tab setup.  I can tell because if you look at the source of your fan page, it is trying to access your page through the facebook proxy which was how FBML fan page tabs worked.  Your tab must now be in iframe tab.  If you look at the actual app itself, the page is rendering fine because it is rendering as an iframe (do a view source on the page.)

This article has a [walkthrough on creating a new iframe application](http://www.vestorlogic.com/2011/02/21/facebook-convert-your-static-fmbl-to-iframe-it%E2%80%99s-not-as-painful-as-you-think/), and you will be able to point it at the [existing page](https://www.sonivoxmi.com/fbpage.asp?pg=fbcomposers&grp=ComposerSeries) you have.  You may need to get a valid SSL certificate to serve the page since a lot of users have SSL always enabled for their Facebook account and may not be able to see the page otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently experienced this myself, and the 404 was caused because the person viewing the app didn't use https in FB, and I didn't have a http copy of the app. Once I copied the app to the public_html from the public_ssl folder, it worked marvellously. Hope this helps someone with a similar problem?

Kind regards,

Kobus